# Checking an array value that isn't a number

Tags: php

Just a quick one..

While running through a multi-array array in a loop.
How do I check the head value..
Not sure if I can explain it properly. but here is the array:

```
Array
(
    [SMS] => Array
        (
            [VoucherCode] => V510
            [VoucherName] => 2000 SMS
            [VoucherAmount] => 450
            [IsPinless] => 1
        )

    [DATA] => Array
        (
            [VoucherCode] => V549
            [VoucherName] => 150MB
            [VoucherAmount] => 29
            [IsPinless] => 1
        )

    [AIRTIME] => Array
        (
            [VoucherCode] => V500
            [VoucherName] => Pinless
            [VoucherAmount] => -1
            [IsPinless] => 1
        )
)
```

So How can I see the "SMS" or "DATA" value in a loop to check if I need to add to that section of the array?

What I have thats not working

```
foreach($GroupArray as $item) {
    if ($item == 'SMS'){
           //Do Stuff..
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "head value"? Do you mean the key of the array? And do you want to check if it's an integer?

Comment: have a look at my multi array. I need to see if the value == 'SMS' which happens to be an array..

Comment: @Christoffer he means the key of the array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code to look like following:

```
foreach($GroupArray as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == 'SMS'){
           //Do Stuff..
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh Gees .. I forgot that.. Sorry to bug everyone with this.. Good ol' Monday morning..

Comment: need to wait 9 minutes..